# Visually what happens when you call same process with ampersand

Tags: c, shell, ubuntu, terminal

I am playing with **`ampersand “&”`**. I understand that in bash shell script the

> *ampersand* is used to **fork** processes but will run in the *background*. This is useful because it allows you to get your prompt back *immediately*, and *run the process in the background*.

Please observe the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int x=5;

void main()
{
   int pid = getpid();
   int y=6;

   printf("[%d] [%p] x = %d\n", pid, &x, x++);
   printf("[%d] [%p] y = %d\n", pid, &y, y++);
}
```

*After successful compilation, I run the code with:*

```
> ./a.out & ./a.out & ./a.out
```

*Output of first run:*

```
[4436] [0x601058] x = 5
[4435] [0x601058] x = 5
[4436] [0x7fff2d481bd8] y = 6
[4435] [0x7fff7ecadd88] y = 6
[4437] [0x601058] x = 5
[4437] [0x7fff6e0741d8] y = 6
```

*Output of second run:*

```
[4469] [0x601058] x = 5
[4469] [0x7fffa00048b8] y = 6
[4470] [0x601058] x = 5
[4470] [0x7fffd447a798] y = 6
[4468] [0x601058] x = 5
[4468] [0x7fffc35dc7b8] y = 6
```

Observations:

- Some print statements appear in different order because each process is running simultaneously.
- Address of variable x is the same on all instances because it’s a global variable.
- Value of x is the same in all instances because it gets reset every time to 5.
- Variable y is only local to main(), therefore its address will be unique in each process.

Here are my questions:

1. The reason why some print statements appear in different order are determined by which process was started first by the OS scheduler?
2. Since variable x is global and seems to keep the same address in all runs/instances. Why isn’t its value shared among processes after the auto increment? Why doesn’t ANY process print an incremented value of x?

Comment: Memory addresses are in **virtual memory**. Since all the processes are running the same program, their virtual memory is laid out the same, so everything will have the same address.

Comment: It sounds like you need to take a course in operating systems, to understand how virtual memory works.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks, very constructive.

Comment: Even without the `&`, the processes are run with a fork.  The relevant difference is that the shell does not wait for the child to finish.  (There are other details as well.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) has its *own [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space)* in [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) (thanks to the processor's [MMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit)). So variable `x` is not *global* to your 3 processes; every process has its own `x`; so address 0x601058 (the printed address of `x`) in process 4436 is not the same location as the "same" address 0x601058 in process 4435.

So (virtual) memory is specific to every process. A process can change its address space using [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html). You could use some advanced techniques to set up some [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) between several processes (but learn more some Linux programming before). See [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) & [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html). You should not (as a newbie) want to use shared memory, because of synchronization issues.

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com), it has several chapters related to your questions.

A multi-threaded process has several [threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29) sharing the *same* address space (and other things like current directory, opened file descriptors, etc...). Read also some POSIX thread [(a.k.a pthread) tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/). Each thread has its own [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

Notice that addresses might not be reproducible from one run to the next one, because of [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

The [Linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) has a [scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29) working on [tasks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_%28computing%29). A scheduled task is either a thread or a (single-threaded) process. The scheduler may [preempt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29#Preemptive_multitasking) tasks at arbitrary moments, and on a multi-core processor you may have several tasks running in parallel (on different cores).

You could also play (on Linux) with [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). If you let your processes sleep e.g. 10 seconds, you could type (e.g. in a different terminal) `cat /proc/4436/maps` while your process 4436 is still running (or asleep).

You might also play with [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), maybe try `strace a.out` to see the relevant [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

Of course, read several times the documentation of [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)

Since the [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) shell is [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), you could study its source code. It does call `fork` a lot!

Comment: Thanks! I am going to make corrections on my diagram and observations. Your answer has touched on most of my questions. Let me marinate on it a bit.

Comment: Your diagram is cute, but it does not show much about what you understand.

Comment: I will update it, as I said I wasn’t happy with it. But I at least want my question and its answer appeal to anyone even if they did not take an OS class.

Comment: Don't use a static diagram. Try to think (in your head) of a "movie". Time is significant!